# failed to find Build Tools revision 8.0.0

Tags: java, php, android, windows

Failed to find Build Tools revision 8.0.0. how I can solve this problem.

Please See this Screen Sort

[image]

Comment: did you download SDK platform?which is inside sdk platform?

Comment: don't install Build Tools 8.0.0 from online... if you have offline version please give me

Answer (score 0):

Click on the link on the error :

> Install Build Tools 8.0.0 and sync project

You will normally get rid of the error

Comment: don't install Build Tools 8.0.0 from online... if you have offline version please give me

Comment: please check here https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.fr/p/android-sdk-800-api-26-o-direct-download.html

Comment: Please follow the step by step on the link